# haskell polymorphic type functions

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

Is it possible in Haskell to have a function that can take a polymorphic type and return a polymorphic type?

For example, I want a function that takes a value, and returns an Int if the value is of type `Foo` and a String if it is of type `Bar`

```
data Foo = One | Two | Three deriving (Show, Read)
data Bar = This | That | TheOther deriving (Show, Read)

doSomething :: Either Foo Bar -> Either Int String
doSomething var = if (typeOf var) == Int then 123 else "string"
```

Is something like this possible?  If not, what is the best practice for routing to another function based on type?

Comment: What are you trying to solve with this function?

Comment: Making a library that computes music theory things (scales, chords, etc).  I have a function that takes either a scale or chord, and a root note, and then returns a list of notes, which is formatted differently depending on the type.  I figured that streamlining this to just illustrate the issue would make it more palatable, but I probably should have just included the function I was actually using

Comment: I think your example was fine - the music stuff would probably have hidden the details/what matters to much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first the things you describe and the `Either Int String` signature seem not to match - I'll try what you describe first (choose the output-type by it's input type):

you can do something very similar to what I think you are trying with type-families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module SO where

data Foo = One | Two | Three deriving (Show, Read)
data Bar = This | That | TheOther deriving (Show, Read)

class PolyMap k where
  type To k :: *
  polyMap :: k -> To k

instance PolyMap Foo where
  type To Foo = Int
  polyMap _ = 123

instance PolyMap Bar where
  type To Bar = String
  polyMap _ = "string"
```

example:

```
λ> polyMap One
123
λ> polyMap That
"string"
```

#### some explanation

What I think you want is to have type-mappings/functions (there is no runtime check with `typeOf` out-of-the box and this would give you some nice type-checking support instead) and there are basically two ways to do it (I am aware of)

- [Type Families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families) which I showed you
- [functional dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) which Cactus did

Both give you (among others) the means to have some way to say: look if I get type A I can say what some associated type B must be (`Foo -> Int` and `Bar -> String`)

This is a deep topic (borderline dependent-types ;)) but I think type-families with classes are not to hard to understand.

The idea I used is to have the class `PolyMap` that provides the `polyMap` function (you can have it named anything you want - `doSomething`, whatever) and there the output type depends on the input type using the `To k` mapping which is `Int` for `Foo` and `String` for `Bar` as stated in the instance-declarations.

---

the other one for your signature is even easier:

```
doSomething :: Either Foo Bar -> Either Int String
doSomething (Left _) = Left 123
doSomething (Right _) = Right "string"
```

example:

```
λ> doSomething (Left One)
Left 123
λ> doSomething (Right That)
Right "string"
```

Comment: That helps.  The solution you proposed for my type signature seems to be as close as it's going to get to doing type-dependent actions inside a function, but it requires explicit knowledge as to what side of Either it's going into.  It seems standard practice to do them in instance declarations.

Comment: if you want `Either` you have to deal with `Left`/`Right` - just as with `Maybe` and `Just`/`Nothing`

Answer (score 3):

You can put `doSomething` in a typeclass keyed on both the domain and the codomain types, with a functional dependency from the domain to the codomain:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances  #-} -- if one of your `to` really is `String`
class DoSomething from to | from -> to where
    doSomething :: from -> to

instance DoSomething Foo Int where -- ...
instance DoSomething Bar String where -- ...
```

Compared with the type family-based solution, this has the benefit that *if the codomain also uniquely determines the domain*, you can add another functional dependency `to -> from`. I don't think type families offer a good way of modelling that.

Comment: soon: [injective type families](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/InjectiveTypeFamilies) ;) - of course in this special case you probably don't need (or even want it) - hard to tell from what we know

Comment: @Carsten: but of course. I must say though, I didn't realize that's going to support open families as well.